# Suitability of ArangoDB for a slightly unusual requirement

Tags: arangodb

I have the following requirement:

1. Have multiple collections that are joined in a query (usual SQL INNER JOIN style).
2. Searches on a document consist of a) finding exact matches and b) range matches against integer values (which could be stored as text if needed). Searches are sparse, so a b-tree is out.

No stemming, ranking, or other processing is required. It's as simple as:

> give me all docs in collection1 where field1 contains 1 or 2 and field2 contains 99 and 100 and field3 contains a value between 1000 and 1003... join this to collection2 where ...

Is this possible in ArangoDB (I assume using ArangoSearch Views)? If so, could anyone give me a point in the right (performant) direction?

Comment: Do you have the option of running this as a Foxx REST endpoint, then you can send a JSON payload to the REST endpoint defining your query, and then have Foxx generate the AQL to execute the query?

Or are you trying to do this query with a single AQL query directly into the collections?

Comment: I haven't got that far, yet. Most likely it would be a single AQL. At this point, I'm trying to determine if ArangoDB can perform the query at all. In PostgreSQL, this would be the equivalent to using a GiST index where ranges and equality can be queried on any indexed fields in any order.

Answer (score 0):

While performance truly depends on the amount and type of data, assuming performance is not working as expected for selecting data, I would try:

A hash index on each of the fields 1 and 2

A skip list index on field 3

Since you mention the data is sparse, I would try turning on the sparse option on the appropriate index. This will cause Arango to index only the data that has non null values for the field on the index (or set of fields). Further, if the non null data was unique I would further try a sparse unique index.

In the end, your mileage will depend on your data as I mentioned before and so will be remedy. Either way the Arango documentation on indexes can be found [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Indexing/)

Oh and before I forget, unlike SQL, the order in which statements appear in the AQL statement does make a difference so try to filter as much data as early as possible.

Happy hunting!